# Can anyone identify this shower handle manufacture

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I need to replace the cartridges but don't see any manufactures identifying marks on the shower handle.[image]

Comment: There's likely a set-screw on the under-side of that handle.  It should come off easily and will likely have markings.  If that doesn't say, you'll see the valve which will be more of a clue.